# Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools

Tags: android, arraylist, array-map

My app is runing well but after i using the ARRAYLIST i have a problem Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.monkeyPatchExistingResources.

I add the support library in the depenceis of the gradle build ( compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:24.2.1') but still not work.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQNbg.png)

Comment: Please give a [mcve].

Comment: what the information [tag:Code-Apprentice] you need to help me